# Double endAdornments when using self-defined endAdornment in Material-UI Input

Tags: material-ui

When I try to use Material-UI Input, I just copied and pasted the code on https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/, especially the password part, However, after I copied that code, it cannot behave as the demo does. When you first time render the component and click on the textfield, there will be 2 endAdornments(on both you can toggle to display password).
[Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9c7v.png)
Here is the code I used:

```
      <Input
        className={classes.input}
        type={values.showPassword ? "text" : "password"}
        value={values.password}
        onChange={handleInputChange("password")}
        endAdornment={
          <InputAdornment position="end">
            <IconButton
              aria-label="toggle password visibility"
              onClick={handleClickShowPassword}
              onMouseDown={handleMouseDownPassword}
            >
              {values.showPassword ? <Visibility /> : <VisibilityOff />}
            </IconButton>
          </InputAdornment>
        }
      />
```

What's weirder is that once you click away(anywhere), the 1st eye just disappears, it behaves as we want.
Does anyone know how to solve that problem?

Here is the sandbox link if anyone wants to playaround:
https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-lamport-t00fb?file=/src/App.tsx:1516-1528

Answer (score 1):

[Compare between Edge and Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gADqy.png)
I think I figure that out. This is due to Edge. If I open it with chrome, there will be no problems. As the picture showed above.

Answer (score 1):

add

```
input::-ms-reveal,
input::-ms-clear {
  display: none;
}
```

to styles file

Answer (score 0):

I used the code (bellow) from [here](https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/#input-adornments) and I could not reproduce the issue:

```js
import React from "react";
import clsx from "clsx";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import Input from "@material-ui/core/Input";
import InputLabel from "@material-ui/core/InputLabel";
import InputAdornment from "@material-ui/core/InputAdornment";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import Visibility from "@material-ui/icons/Visibility";
import VisibilityOff from "@material-ui/icons/VisibilityOff";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    display: "flex",
    flexWrap: "wrap"
  },
  margin: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1)
  },
  withoutLabel: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(3)
  },
  textField: {
    width: "25ch"
  }
}));

export default function InputAdornments() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [values, setValues] = React.useState({
    amount: "",
    password: "",
    weight: "",
    weightRange: "",
    showPassword: false
  });

  const handleChange = (prop) => (event) => {
    setValues({ ...values, [prop]: event.target.value });
  };

  const handleClickShowPassword = () => {
    setValues({ ...values, showPassword: !values.showPassword });
  };

  const handleMouseDownPassword = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <div>
        <FormControl className={clsx(classes.margin, classes.textField)}>
          <InputLabel htmlFor="standard-adornment-password">
            Password
          </InputLabel>
          <Input
            id="standard-adornment-password"
            type={values.showPassword ? "text" : "password"}
            value={values.password}
            onChange={handleChange("password")}
            endAdornment={
              <InputAdornment position="end">
                <IconButton
                  aria-label="toggle password visibility"
                  onClick={handleClickShowPassword}
                  onMouseDown={handleMouseDownPassword}
                >
                  {values.showPassword ? <Visibility /> : <VisibilityOff />}
                </IconButton>
              </InputAdornment>
            }
          />
        </FormControl>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I try to copy your code into my sandbox. Unfortunately, It will have the same issues with mine. I didn't do any modification and copy paste all the classes/import

Comment: Both you and my code are correct. It is due to the new Edge. If you open Edge and chrome with the same sandbox link, they produce different behaviors.

Comment: Right. So this issue is not with `mui`, but is there a way to avoid it with `js` code?